# Mysql query to update row and return the new value with the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have this simple query which updates products qty:

```
$updprqty='UPDATE products set     
available_qty = available_qty - '.$qty.' 
WHERE id = '.$pid.'';
```

What else should I add so I can get the new value of available_qty ?
Thanks

Comment: Run a select with `$pid`

Comment: I don't want to run a second query - has to be done with same one - isn't possible?

Comment: You can run a select within update but you cannot run a update within select

Answer (score 0):

```
$updprqty='UPDATE products set     
available_qty = (select available_qty from products where id = ' .$pid . ') - '.$qty.' 
WHERE id = '.$pid.'';
```

Introducing alias

```
$updprqty='update products set available_qty =  x.available_qty from (select available_qty, id from products) - '.$qty.' where id = ' .$pid . ')  as x where id = x.id';
```

Comment: @Satish Sharma - than what is the proper way to get it?